# Render child action given HttpVerb

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Now I have two actions, one for **HttpGet** and one for **HttpPost**, and the **HttpGet** one is mostly for child actions, so my code looks like:

```
[ActionName("Comments")]
[HttpGet]
public void CommentList(string postId) {
    // This is for SEO
    if (!ControllerContext.IsChildAction) {
        return Redirect("/post/" + postId);
    }

    // Get list
    return View("CommentList", list);
}

[ActionName("Comments")]
[HttpPost]
public void PostComment(Comment comment) {
    // Save to DB
    // Get the parent post
    // return View("Post", post);
}
```

Unfortunately, in my **Post** view, I render the **CommentList** as a child action:

```
@Html.Action("Comments", new { postId = Model.Id });
```

The problem is, when I submit a comment with a **POST** request, after the comment is saved to DB, it executes the **Post** view, which renders **"Comments"** child action. Here when **"Comments"** child actions is rendered, the HttpVerb is still **POST**, so router gives the **PostComment** action, which again (after some validation failure) renders the **Post** view, which renders the **"Comments"** child action...

It causes an infinite recursion, results a `StackOverflowException` and crashes my web server.

So, is there any method to force my `@Html.Action("Comments")` executing the **CommentList** action, am I able to pass a **HttpVerb** or something like to router?

Thanks

Comment: If you have the comments list as a property of a post, you can call HTML.RenderPartial in the Post view to render the comments list. this will not create page re-rendering

Comment: I noticed your SEO comment in the source. You could/should be using routing if you want to expose prettier URLs and not handling this in your controller

Comment: Thanks @MarkG, I've discovered this is not for SEO, but a unremoved redundant code branch (previously this action is for ajax to load all comments), I've already deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use the PRG that us Post Redirect Get like

```
[ActionName("Comments")]
[HttpPost]
public void PostComment(Comment comment) {
    // Save to DB
    // redirect to the Get Method
    return RedirectToAction("Comments",new {postId=comment.postId.ToString()});
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've noticed PRG a good choice before, but encountered another problem: after I saved my data to db, I have to render the view with a lot extra data (a friendly notice message, different `<title>`, etc...), PRG is hard to handle such situation (may be I should use Session to store these data?)

Comment: You can use `TempData` if the data is required to be "passed" from your post handler to your view action

Comment: as @MarkG mentioned you can use `TempData` but also you can make a model class of additional data you want to show and pass it to the GET method as the `postId` is passed in the answer above